# Connecting methods from outer class

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I have two classes App(main class) and OptionsWin(class to create a toplevel window).The classes structure is like

```py
import tkinter as tk

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        #other methods
        self.opt_win = OptionsWin(self.root,'Circle')

    def show(self):
        #get value of the RadioButton
        pass
```

```py
class OptionsWin():
    def __init__(self, root, shape=None):
        self.parent = root
        self.root = tk.Toplevel(self.parent)
        if shape == 'Circle':
            self.create_circle_opt()
    def create_circle_opt(self):
        #Other Widgets
        # Types of Circles
        self.radVar = tk.IntVar()
        self.radVar.set(0)

        tk.Radiobutton(self.root, text='Equal Ellipse', variable=self.radVar,
                       value=0, command=None).grid(column=2, row=0, padx=10,
                                                   pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
        tk.Radiobutton(self.root, text='Flat Ellipse', variable=self.radVar,
                       value=10, command=None).grid(column=2, row=1, padx=10,
                                                   pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
        tk.Radiobutton(self.root, text='Tall Ellipse', variable=self.radVar,
                       value=20, command=None).grid(column=2, row=2, padx=10,
                                                   pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
```

I want to connect the RadioButtons command arg to the App class show function.
Is there any way to do it or a better way to organize my classes structure to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

So, you have the value of the radio button stored in a variable on the OptionsWin instance- self.radVar. If you have access to that instance in your App instance, you can easily reference it. It actually looks like thats what you're going for here-

```
class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        #other methods
        self.opt_win(self.root,'Circle')
```

We don't see a definition of self.opt_win. My guess is that this was supposed to be

```
self.opt_win = OptionsWin(self.root,'Circle')
```

In that case, your show method would just be

```
def show(self):
    #get value of the RadioButton
    return self.opt_win.radVar
```

If my guess was wrong about opt_win (maybe its a constructor method), the basis of the answer is `keep a reference to the OptionsWin instance so you can access the variables on it`

Edit--

To be able to reference the parent from the child as well, you could do-

```
class OptionsWin():
    def __init__(self, app, shape=None):
        self.app = app
        self.root = tk.Toplevel(app.root)
        if shape == 'Circle':
            self.create_circle_opt()

    def show(self):
        self.app.show()
```

And then your app constructer becomes

```
class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        # pass self into the child, and then it can reference this object
        self.opt_win = OptionsWin(self,'Circle')
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I made a mistake and have edited in the question

Comment: I also want to connect the function 'show' to the command arg of the RadioButton. How can I do that ?

Comment: You already have a reference to root in the child class... so `self.parent.show()`

Comment: I tried it but as @stovfl mentioned it gives `"AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'show'"`

Comment: Good point, I didn't go back and look at it- that's not a reference to App! Use stovfl's suggestion, store a reference to the actual App object on the child window.

Comment: How can I do that (new to OOP) ?

Answer (score 0):

How about making `OptionsWin` a member in `App`?

```
class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.options_win = OptionsWin()
        #other methods
        self.opt_win(self.root,'Circle')
```

Comment: Can I somehow reference the App.show inside the OptionsWin by doing this ??

Comment: No. Its the other way around. The App `show()` can use OptionsWin attributes.